# Writing a text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I write exactly the test below using python into a text file? This is required when I have to write several text files with different parameters.

```
MY_FILE = E:\test.jpg

BAND_SUBSET = ( 1 0 0 )

SPATIAL_SUBSET1 = ( 25.0 50.0 )
SPATIAL_SUBSET2 = ( 25.0 50.0 )

PARA1 = (
 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 )

END = END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('fileName', 'w') as f:
    f.write(yourString)
```

where

```
>>> yourString = """MY_FILE = E:\test.jpg

BAND_SUBSET = ( 1 0 0 )

SPATIAL_SUBSET1 = ( 25.0 50.0 )
SPATIAL_SUBSET2 = ( 25.0 50.0 )

PARA1 = (
 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 )

END = END"""
```

You could replace the values by using the following code.

```
with open('fileName', 'w') as f:
    f.write(yourString.format(band_subset, spatial_subset_1, spatial_subset_2, para1))
```

where

```
yourString = """MY_FILE = E:\test.jpg

BAND_SUBSET = {}

SPATIAL_SUBSET1 = {}
SPATIAL_SUBSET2 = {}

PARA1 = {}

END = END"""
```

Always use the `help` function or consult The Python Docs.

```
write(...)
    write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.
```

Comment: yes, but i have to input band_subset, para1 etc from program, i mean they are defined as variable Sukrit Kalra @Sukrit Kalra

Comment: How are your variables stored? As Tuples?

Comment: as string  @Sukrit Kalra

Comment: thank you , i accepted your answer. could you please explain me the meaning of """ @Sukrit Kalra

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as fp:
  fp.write('''MY_FILE = E:\test.jpg

BAND_SUBSET = ( 1 0 0 )

SPATIAL_SUBSET1 = ( 25.0 50.0 )
SPATIAL_SUBSET2 = ( 25.0 50.0 )

PARA1 = (
 0.0 0.0 0.0
 0.0 0.0 0.0 )

END = END''')
```

Comment: yes, but i have to input band_subset, para1 etc from program, i mean they are defined as variable Sukrit Kalra @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: So what. Are you asking how to put them into a string?